# Saving an (mm/dd/yyyy) date format doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

Am trying to create a user with an expiration date ("05/30/2015" i.e "mm/dd/yyyy") but it returns nil for expiration date.

```
u = User.new
=> #<User id: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, email: nil, expiration: nil, remote_id_string: nil, remote_created_at: nil, phone_number: nil, company: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 

u.expiration = "05/30/2015"
=> "05/30/2015" 

u.expiration
=> nil
```

But rearranging the format as (yyyy/mm/dd) worked

```
u.expiration = "2015/05/30"
=> "2015/05/30"

u.expiration
=> Sat, 30 May 2015
```

I tried fixing this by installing "gem validates_timeliness" and I used "parser.us_use_formats" for the date format "05/30/2015", it still returns nil.

How do I parse the date format so it doesn't return nil and accepts this("05/30/2015" i.e "mm/dd/yyyy") format?

Comment: @CamllmeSurge Look into the answer, let me know if it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use like this,

```
u.expiration = Date.strptime("05/30/2015","%m/%d/%Y")
=> "Sat, 30 May 2015"

u.expiration
=> "Sat, 30 May 2015"
```

Comment: I really appreciate your contribution, that was helpful. but I was getting my date from a date picker and I had to go specify the format I wanted. But this was helpful. Thanks.